# Merge tags [std] and [stl]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

The C++ standard library is often (though technically slightly incorrectly) referred to as "STL". Consequently, [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl) is the conventional tag for C++ questions that touch the C++ standard library functionality.

In addition, there's [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std), probably in reference to the fact that the namespace of the C++ standard library is called `std`. This tag is vastly less commonly used and should probably be treated as a duplicate of [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl).

The [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) tag description also refers to Ruby, but [only five questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std%20ruby?mode=all) are tagged as [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) and [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std).

I suggest manually retagging these questions and then making [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) a synonym for [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl).

Comment: No. Though often confused these refer to completely different things.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That’s clearly false if you look at the actual questions. Furthermore, you seem to refer to the fact that “STL” ≠ standard library. But even industry veterans are happy to use the term STL. So you’ve already lost this fight, and *it’s utterly irrelevant*. I’m concerned with practical matters here — namely the usefulness of the tags. And as it stands the tags can be improved.

Comment: _@Konrad_ May be the information that [tag:stl] refers to that ancient HP implementation is useless. In so far I agree.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The information/tag wiki is one thing; by all means let’s edit this but actually having questions tagged usefully is much more important.

Comment: _@Konrad_ I've got some doubts these tags add any value over the regular [tag:c++] et al. in general. If someone asks about c++ the scope is pretty clear even without these tags.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There are plenty of questions about C++ which don’t touch the standard library at all. But I see your point that having the tag isn’t crucial. Having two different ones is still wrong though. I’m frankly surprised at the vehemence with which this ostensibly straightforward proposal is being opposed (see votes): I see *zero* upsides to keeping the current situation.

Comment: Perhaps we can have [tag:sgi-stl] for the genuinely STL-related question. But that excludes people who want to tag as both ([tag:eastl] and [tag:stl]) or ([tag:stlport] and [tag:stl]). I haven't looked into actual candidates for these tags, but let's not close the door on the possibility of finding them, and decide how we want to handle them

Comment: Good idea @sehe, perhaps an answer to expand on this?

Answer (score 5):

I'd mostly agree with you, but we keep the likes of [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) because there are some people with question specific to that. The same applies to STL, it's not 100% synonymous with STD, and so they should remain distinct.

Comment: The difference is that people use [tag:c++03] correctly and there’s in fact no big risk of using it wrongly. Conversely, virtually nobody uses the tag [tag:stl] as distinct from [tag:std]. *If* that were the case I’d agree that the distinction is useful. But it simply isn’t.

Comment: I think the reasoning behind keeping them distinct is still good enough. The fact that it's rarely, if ever, used doesn't mean we should remove that separation.

Comment: I think you’re still making a purely theoretical argument. In reality, benefits and costs need to be weighed, and while the benefit seems to be purely hypothetical (or, if existent, negligible), the cost of having the two tags is that incorrect tagging effectively reduces the tags’ usefulness drastically.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Not really. What thecosh seems to suggest is merely a mass re-tag. That's different from actually merging the tags. See. Re-labeling is not the same as altering the labels

Comment: Oh yes, any STL tag that should be actually STD should be re-tagged as such. If you've not gone through all the STL tags and reviewed them, then suggesting they be merged seems premature