# Rename C++ standard library tags to use consistent naming scheme

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The proposed tag change from e.g. [std-variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-variant) to [stdvariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdvariant) may be purely cosmetical, but it would improve consistency. Major tags which reference parts of the C++ standard library use the latter format as well (not an exhaustive list):

- [stdvector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdvector) (2159)
- [stdmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdmap) (1195)
- [stdset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdset) (243)
- [stdhash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdhash) (50)
- [stdstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdstring) (959)
- [stdstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdstack) (3)
- [stdarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdarray) (294)
- [stdatomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdatomic) (332)

Some other tags use a `-` separator. These are typically tags with far fewer posts (this is an exhaustive list):

- [std-bitset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-bitset) (85)
- [std-call-once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-call-once) (7)
- [std-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-function) (646)
- [std-filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-filesystem) (88)
- [std-future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-future) (30)
- [std-pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-pair) (640)
- [std-source-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-source-location) (8)

For the sake of consistency, I propose renaming all tags to use only one naming scheme. I find the `std-xx` scheme more readable, but seeing that the most used tags use the `stdxx` scheme, it might make more sense to keep it that way.

[**Which do you prefer? Here is a StrawPoll!**](https://www.strawpoll.me/20860902)

Comment: I too find `std-` more readable - I wonder if it  wasn't used because of tag name limits, or if there's some other reason. I assume typing in "stdarray" would bring up [tag:stdarray] _and_ [tag:std-array]

Comment: What bothers me more than the inconsistent dashes is: Why does C++ get to have the `std(-)` prefix? Why is it `stdvector` (or `std-vector`) rather than `cpp-vector` (or `cpp-std-vector` or some other variant)? That tag in particular is really bad as far as tags go, as its description is just “A sequence type defined as part of the Standard Library.”, which doesn't even mention C++, just like its long description. C++ isn't the only language to have a standard library, and is not even [the only language to name it `std`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html).

Comment: @mcarton the anticlimactic answer to *why* is: For historical reasons. C++ had been the only language to use the `std::` prefix for decades until Rust came along in 2010. It was simply the first. [tag:stdvector] is older than the first version of Rust. Personally I find Rust's use of the `std::` prefix a bad decision, since in many cases searching for this will bring up C++ results. They could have just used `rust::` and it would have been almost as short with no conflicts.

Comment: @J.Schultke I know that C++ was first and is way more common, but it doesn't make “A sequence type defined as part of the Standard Library.” a good description, and it doesn't mean that things can't change to be less ambiguous.

Comment: @mcarton Maybe a more valid justification than purely “it’s historical” is that this is very widely what people are used to searching for (due to history, of course). People are very used to the fact that searching for “std vector” (rather than “cpp vector”) brings up the correct result — here and elsewhere. I don’t think (but I may be wrong) that Rust users have the same expectation.

Comment: As far as consistency goes, the following are still open: [Merge tags `std` and `stl`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336041/merge-tags-std-and-stl) and [What is the difference between the tags `std` and `c++-standard-library`?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398798/what-is-the-difference-between-the-tags-std-and-c-standard-library) (with more background [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library)).

Comment: `c++-std-vector` would be much better.

Comment: @mcarton It would be possible to tag some questions with [c++][std-vector] and others with [rust][std-vector], where [[tag:std-vector]] doesn't have to be language-specific. A similar thing happened with the [[tag:async-await]] tag which for a long time was C#-focused before other languages like JavaScript or Python came along.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Why adding c++ if that is already the main language tag anyway. I like  [c++][std-vector] and  [rust][std-vector] much more.

Comment: I'd say the strawpoll here is unnecessary. It's a very flawed system (I can vote as many times as I want), and we already have a ranking system here: votes. You can simply write an answer for either option and let the voting take care of it.

Comment: Related: upon reading this, I realized the [tag:std] is messed up. Made a separate thread here: [Fixing the std and stdlib synonym tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400794/fixing-the-std-and-stdlib-synonym-tags).

Comment: @Trilarion Because tags are not linked to one another

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings But where would be the advantage of tagging a question with [c++] and [c++-std-vector]?

Comment: @Trilarion So that people can find it by subscribing to C++ questions, and so that people can find it by searching for questions about C++'s `std::vector<T, Alloc>` types. The same advantage of any other tag. Remember: tags are not about having some information on the post itself; they are about _discovering_ and _finding_ posts.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Maybe we need a "this tag is often used together with these other tags, click on another tag to additionally limit your search" feature. Then we would not need to manually code it in the tag names.

Comment: @Trilarion Tag hierarchies have been suggested and rejected before, and I'm fine with that ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Automatically computed tag correlations or clusterings are far simpler than a hierarchy and haven't been rejected afaik but also haven't been implemented so far. That's why we are stuck with long and longer tag names. It's the only thing we can do, but I'm not a particular fan of it.

Answer (score 7):

I propose to add the dash to all tags which currently do not have it, i.e. change [stdvector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdvector) to [std-vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-vector), because it is easier to read.

Comment: I've made the answer community wiki, please feel free to add reasons and arguments in favour of adding the dash.

Answer (score -4):

I think the `std` prefix is misleading and confusing. To boldly claim that `std` is C++ specific doesn't hold well. The C++ language support for `std::` was very shaky prior year C++98 standardization, so C++ has not claimed that keyword for *that* long, only since 1998. Whereas C and UNIX had `std` prefixes since the early 1970s. And there's likely lots of `std-whatever` outside the scope of C and C++.

Then we have the C library header tags that are named [stdio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdio), [stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib), [stdint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdint), [stddef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stddef) etc. These are also C++ headers, but these headers are actually named `stdio.h` etc, unlike the C++ ones.

`std::vector` etc is not the name of a library, it's the name of a class residing in the `std::` namespace. So it's already very confusing in a C++ only context: does the tag [stdvector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdvector) refer to the class or the header? Then bring in all the ambiguity with other languages on top of that.

I think [c++-vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-vector) is a better alternative.

Comment: If the naming scheme `std-vector` was used, then it would actually become easy to distinguish these C++ types from `stdio` and the like. I also don't see the ambiguity of `std::vector` and `<vector>` as a problem. You never use one without the other so for tag-purposes, they are interchangeable. `c++-vector` has the same ambiguity, if not more. Does `c++-vector` refer to `<vector>`? Without the `std` prefix in the tag, one might think so.

Comment: Personally, I really don't care about the Rust ambiguity. Rusticians are used to finding C++ results when searching for `std something` anyways, so this won't change anything for them. And C++ devs are used to finding C++ results when searching for `std::`. If anything, blame Rust for using `std::` when `rust::` would have been perfectly fine and nearly as short.

Answer (score -8):

I propose to change all tags to not use the dash, i.e change [std-bitset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-bitset) to [stdbitset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdbitset), because the majority of tags relating to the standard library already use it.